# Updating state from recursively rendered component in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recursion, immutability

I am in need of updating deeply nested object in a React state from a recursively rendered component. The items look like this and can be nested dynamically:

```
const items = [
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "Item 1",
    isChecked: true,
    children: []
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    name: "Item 3",
    isChecked: false,
    children: [
      {
        id: "3.1",
        name: "Child 1",
        isChecked: false,
        children: [
          {
            id: "3.1.1",
            name: "Grandchild 1",
            isChecked: true,
            children: []
          },
          {
            id: "3.1.2",
            name: "Grandchild 2",
            isChecked: true,
            children: []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: "3.2",
        name: "Child 2",
        isChecked: false,
        children: []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I have a problem figuring out how to update the top level state from within a deeply nested component, because it only "knows" about itself, not the entire data structure.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    items
  };

  recursivelyRenderItems(items) {
    return (
      <ul>
        {items.map(item => (
        <li key={item.id}>
          {item.name}
          <input type="checkbox" checked={item.isChecked} onChange={(event) => {
            // TODO: Update the item's checked status
          }} />
          {this.recursivelyRenderItems(item.children)}
        </li>
    ))}
      </ul>

    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.recursivelyRenderItems(this.state.items)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

How can I achieve this, please?

Comment: You fire an event that propagates up, and one or more of its ancestors will handle it

Answer (score 0):

This works in your fiddle you posted.

Basically, each component needs to know about its `item.isChecked` and its parent's `isChecked`. So, create a component that takes 2 props, `item` and `parentChecked` where the latter is a boolean from the parent and the former becomes an mutable state variable in the constructor.

Then, the component simply updates its checked state in the event handler and it all flows down in the render method:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import items from "./items";

class LiComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      item: props.item
    }
  }

  render() {
    var t = this;
    return (
      <ul>
            <li key={t.state.item.id}>
              {t.state.item.name}
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                checked={t.state.item.isChecked || t.props.parentChecked}
                onChange={event => {
                  t.setState({item: {...t.state.item, isChecked: !t.state.item.isChecked}})
                }}
              />
            </li>
            {t.state.item.children.map(item => (
              <LiComponent item={item} parentChecked={t.state.item.isChecked}/>
            ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    items
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.items.map(item => (
        <LiComponent item={item} parentChecked={false} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/treelist-component-ywebq

Comment: I created a code sandbox to make it clearer. I basically want to be able to toggle the `isChecked` property in the whole tree. https://codesandbox.io/s/treelist-component-rtknn

Comment: See my edits and the new sandbox for a working example

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

Create an `updateState` function that takes two args: `id` and `newState`. Since your `ids` already tell you what item you are updating: `3, 3.1, 3.1.1`, you can from any of the recursive items call your update function with the `id` of the item you want to modify. Split the `id` by dots and go throw your items recursively to find out the right one.

For example from the recursive rendered item `3.1.1`, can call `updateState` like this: `updateState('3.1.1', newState)`.

```js
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import items from "./items";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    items
  };

  updateState = item => {
    const idArray = item.id.split(".");
    const { items } = this.state;

    const findItem = (index, children) => {
      const id = idArray.slice(0, index).join(".");
      const foundItem = children.find(item => item.id === id);
      if (index === idArray.length) {
        foundItem.isChecked = !item.isChecked;
        this.setState(items);
        return;
      } else {
        findItem(index + 1, foundItem.children);
      }
    };

    findItem(1, items);
  };

  recursivelyRenderItems(items) {
    return (
      <ul>
        {items.map(item => (
          <li key={item.id}>
            {item.name}
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              checked={item.isChecked}
              onChange={event => this.updateState(item)}
            />
            {this.recursivelyRenderItems(item.children)}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.recursivelyRenderItems(this.state.items)}</div>;
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

[Working example.](https://codesandbox.io/s/treelist-component-ceifw)