# The changes made to state variable in my react app is not updated to sub function calls

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recursion, state, jsx

```
const [ change , setChange ] = useState(0);
const funct = () => {
    if (change === 100){
        return 0;
    }
    setChange((pre) => {
        return pre + 10
    });
    funct()
}
```

if I call the function ***fuct()*** when any event occur , it will have to call itself (recursive function) until the value of change become 100. But here the function is running infinitely(infinte recursion). This is because the state variable is not changing at every instant of **setChange()** call.

WHY ?
WHY DID THE STATE IS NOT CHANGED BETWEEN RECURSIVE FUNCTION CALLS ?

Comment: could this one help you?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60566919/updating-state-from-recursively-rendered-component-in-react-js

Comment: The issue is that all the state updates are enqueued and only processed ***after*** `funct` (the first initial one) returns. If your code really is as simple as your snippet I suggest passing the value of "pre"/"change" to each recursive call until you reach the base case. I'm guessing your use case isn't as simple as this snippet though. Perhaps we could provide better help if we understood what your code is attempting to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

> WHY ? WHY DID THE STATE IS NOT CHANGED BETWEEN RECURSIVE FUNCTION CALLS ?

Since `funct()` is triggered via React-based event, [state updates are batched](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14259#issuecomment-439632622).

In order not to batch state update, the trigger should come outside of React-based events, like `setInterval()`.

With that said, here's an example using `useEffect()` hook with `setInterval()`.

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

const App = (props) => {
  const [change, setChange] = useState(0);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const t = setInterval(() => (
      setChange((change) => (change + 10))
    ), 1000);
    
    return () => clearInterval(t);
  }, [change]);
  
  return (
    <div>{`Change: ${change}`}</div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the dispatch function of useState (**setChange** in this case) is a async operation and doesn't update the state as soon as it is called. You can try this code instead:

```
const [change, setChange] = useState(0);
const funct = (pre = 0) => {
    if (pre === 100) {
        return 0;
    }
    setChange(pre + 10);
    funct(pre + 10);
}
```

Here, the use of setChange can be avoided but, considering your original code might required that, I have provided the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please make a note! The state will never be useful until the line of codes is left to process. you cannot use useState in that way:

```
const [mystate, setState] = useState(0);

const getSum = () => {

  setState(10);

  sum = mystate + 10 //And expect 20? No, you will never get 20 but you will receive 10.

}
```

always complete your code using let or var and send back the results to the state.

```
const [ change , setChange ] = useState(0);
let iter = 0;
const funct = () => {
    if (iter === 100){
        setChange(iter);
    }
    else{
         iter=iter+10
         funct();
    }
}
```

You cannot use "change" to return the count value every time the function runs but you can use "iter"! In the end you will have change with total values.

Comment: your explanation is correct but i don't agree that using local mutable state is the correct way to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

setState/usestate are Asynchronous functions i.e. we can't setState on one line and assume state has changed on the next.

You can try this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(change!==0){
        funct();
    }
    
}, [change])

const funct = () => {
     if (change === 100){
        return 0;
    }
     setChange((pre) => {
        return pre + 10
    });
    
}
```

Comment: `setState` and `useState` ***are not*** asynchronous functions, but react state updates ***are*** asynchronous. It's a subtle, but important, distinction.