# How to do recursive tree array function?

Tags: javascript, recursion, treeview

I have an infinitely deep folders tree-array. Each folder have a "hasPermission" boolean. What I want to achieve is when a parent folder's (that can be located anywhere in the tree) "hasPermission" changes, all it's children "hasPermission" will also change - of course, the grandparent folders "hasPermission" will not change.

For example, in the folder tree below. If folderId: '2.1' changes permission, folderId: '3.1' will also change; the others will stay the same.

```
const example = [
  {
    folderId: '1',
    hasPermission: false,
    children: [
      {
        folderId: '2.1',
        hasPermission: false,
        children: [
          {
            folderId: '3.1',
            hasPermission: false,
            children: [],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        folderId: '2.2',
        hasPermission: false,
        children: [],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

This function changes the "hasPermission" recursively.

```
  const changeChildrenPermission = (
    folders
  ) => {
    return folders.map(
      ({ id, children, hasPermission }) => ({
        id,
        hasPermission: (hasPermission === false && true) || false,
        children: changeChildrenPermission(children),
      })
    );
  };
```

Here is what I have so far, I'm trying to look up the tree for the selectedId, if it
matches, then call the "changeChildrenPermission" function.

```
  const setPermissionChange = (
    folders,
    selectedId
  ) => {
    const a = folders.map((folder) => {
      if (folder.id === selectedId) {
       return {
          id: folder.folderId,
          hasPermission: (hasPermission === false && true) || false,
          children: changeChildrenPermission(folder.children),
        };
    });
  };
```

Not sure what to do afterwards.

Comment: Could you give a complete reproducible example?

Comment: sure thing, I'll update it with expected outcome

Comment: I think "2.1" should be "1.1.1"

Comment: Ahh yes, thank you kol, I've updated it. And thank you for the solution below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// visitFolders: Walks the folder tree recursively and calls visitFolder for every folder.
// - If visitFolder returns true for a folder, the walk stops immediately.
// - If you want to visit all folders, visitFolder should return false.
//   (Returning false can be omitted, because the default return value of functions is undefined, which is falsy.)
const visitFolders = (folders, visitFolder) => {
  for (let folder of folders) {
    if (visitFolder(folder) || visitFolders(folder.children, visitFolder)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
};

const findFolderById = (folders, id) => {
  let folderWithId = null;
  visitFolders(folders, folder => {
    if (folder.id === id) {
      folderWithId = folder;
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  });
  return folderWithId;
};

const setFolderPermission = (folder, hasPermission) => {
  visitFolders([folder], folder => {
    folder.hasPermission = hasPermission;
    return false;
  });
};

const folders = [
  {
    id: "1",
    hasPermission: true,
    children: [
      {
        id: "1.1",
        hasPermission: true,
        children: []
      },
      {
        id: "1.2",
        hasPermission: true,
        children: [
          {
            id: "1.2.1",
            hasPermission: true,
            children: []
          },
          {
            id: "1.2.2",
            hasPermission: true,
            children: []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: "1.3",
        hasPermission: true,
        children: []
      },
      {
        id: "1.4",
        hasPermission: true,
        children: []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    hasPermission: true,
    children: [
      {
        id: "2.1",
        hasPermission: true,
        children: []
      },
      {
        id: "2.2",
        hasPermission: true,
        children: []
      }
    ]
  }
];

const folder = findFolderById(folders, "1.2");
if (folder !== null) {
  setFolderPermission(folder, false);
}
visitFolders(folders, folder => {
  console.log(folder.id, folder.hasPermission);
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Can I ask, for function "const visitFolders = (folders, visitFolder)", how would I type "visitFolder"? And when you use it in:

const findFolderById = (folders, id) => {
  let folderWithId = null;
  visitFolders(folders, folder => {

where is this "folder" variable coming from?

Comment: I added an explanation before `visitFolders`. It's a helper function which recursively walks the folder tree, that is, it visits every folder, and calls `visitFolder` on every folder. The `visitFolder` function can do anything you want.

Comment: Hi Koi, sorry to bother you again, I want to use this in React with const [folders, setFolders] = useState(initialFoldersData);

when I try to setFolders with folder, it rerenders too many times. 
visitFolders(folders, folder => {
  setFolders(folder)
  return false;
});

Comment: Search for recursive tree rendering in React: https://coderrocketfuel.com/article/recursion-in-react-render-comments-with-nested-children, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60566919/updating-state-from-recursively-rendered-component-in-react-js etc.